# up/down arrow adjustments in a spinbutton

Tags: python-3.x, gtk

How do I get an up/down arrow adjustmnet like in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxMA6.png) instead of the +/- adjustments.  I didn't see anything the the spinbutton documentation addressing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You image is old school GTK ([probably from GTK2](https://pike.lysator.liu.se/generated/manual/modref/ex/predef_3A_3A/GTK2/SpinButton.html)). If you look at the widgets gallery from [GTK3](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/visual_index.html) and [GTK4](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/visual_index.html), you will see that the spin button has changed looks.

Looking at the different options in Glade, I found that `GtkSpinButton` [inherits from `GtkOrientable`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.SpinButton.html#hierarchy). You can set orientation to be either horizontal or vertical. I tried both options in Glade and neither gives the result you are looking for.

**Vertical**

[image: Vertical]

**Horizontal**

[image: Horizontal]

In both cases, you have those -/+ you want to get rid of.

So to answer your question, sadly : no.

Comment: Thanks for the answer even though it wasn't the one I was hoping for.  You are also correct that it was taken from a gtk2 script which I was trying to port to python3/gtk3.

Comment: And unfortunately, `GtkSpinButton` doesn't have a `get_children()` method, so there's no way to hack into its inner workings to change it.